# Simple implement of the color-picker plugin

Tags: jquery, include, color-picker

I recently started using colorpicker of http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker

It seems to me a very good plugin, but I have a big problem: I can not get it to work on my site.

Use this code to include it in the 'header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colorpicker.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/colorpicker.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

#colorSelector {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
</style>
```

In the body

```
<p>
    <div id="colorSelector"><div style="background-color: #0000ff"></div></div>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
    color: '#0000ff',
    onShow: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    },
    onHide: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
        return false;
    },
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
        $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
    }
});
</script>
```

I think it's a very simple problem to solve, but I do not understand what is wrong.

Thanks in advance to all

Comment: Could you tell us what errors are shown? Maybe in the developer tools of your browser?

Comment: Thanks first of all for the reply. However simply do not see any effect, it may be an error in the inclusion of the plugin?

Comment: I understand that no effect is shown. But if you are using Chrome, for example, it will show you any javascript errors that happened. This could help us to identity the problem.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js. Origin http://127.0.0.1 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. `  This error might mean something? thanks again

Comment: This error is pretty know, it says that you cannot make an asynchronous call to another domain. Example, using localhost you cannot perform an AJAX call to googleapis.com. But I cannot see in your script code any AJAX call...do you have more javascript code in your page?

Comment: No one in the main question is all the code js present ... I hope you can help me because my project is locked.
I could change the link to jquery?

Comment: Yes for sake, download a local version copy of the jquery.

Comment: Now there is no probleme and as you suggested I downloaded jquery.
There continues to be no result, even though I basically copied the code on the official site as you can see.

Thanks for the 'infinite patience

Comment: Lets fix this...give a second.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a working example.

First we link all necessary resources for color picker:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colorpicker.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/colorpicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/eye.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/layout.js?ver=1.0.2"></script>
</head>
```

Second I just create a div element:

```
<div id="colorSelector"></div>
```

Finally we setup the plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#colorSelector').ColorPicker();
    });
</script>
```

Now you just need to handle the events that you need "onChange, onPreview..."

Edit:

All resources files were downloaded from the color picker site that you provided.